# PostgreSQL: Creating a function which accepts multiple values

Tags: postgresql, function, types, parameters

I want to write a function which will add insert record and then insert one or more records in a related table. I think I know what to do inside the function, but I don’t know what the function signature should look like.

Here is a mockup sample:

```
CREATE TABLE sales(id SERIAL, customer id, sold date);
CREATE TABLE saleitems(SERIAL, sale int, details varchar, price numeric(6,2));

SELECT addSale(42, '2016-01-01',
    values ('stuff',13),('more stuff',42),('things',3.14),('etc',0)) items(price,details));

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addSale(customer,sold,items) RETURNS int AS
$$
--  I think I can handle the rest
$$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

The salient points:

1. I would like to be able to use the `VALUES (…) name(…)` construct as an argument — is this possible?
2. The real problem, I think, is the last parameter `items`. What is the appropriate type of this?
3. I would like the language to be `SQL`, since my next step is to translate this into other dialects (MySQL & SQL Server). However, I’ll do whatever is needed.

Eventually I will wrap the code body inside a transaction, and return the new `sales.id` value.

The question is: what is the correct parameter to accept a table expression in the `VALUES` form?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet here is to create a new type that holds the details and price of a product:

```
CREATE TYPE product_details AS (
  details varchar,
  price   numeric(6,2)
);
```

Then you can define a function parameter of type `product_details[]`, i.e. an array of product details. Since you want to have a SQL function and need to retrieve the value of the serial column of one insert for use in another insert, you need a CTE:

```
CREATE FUNCTION addSale(_customer int, _sold int, _items product_details[]) RETURNS int AS
$$
  WITH s AS (
    INSERT INTO sales (customer, sold) VALUES (_customer, _sold) RETURNING id;
  )
  INSERT INTO saleitems (sale, details, price)
    SELECT s.id, i.d, i.p
    FROM s, unnest(_items) i(d, p);
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

And then you call the function like so:

```
SELECT addSale(42, '2016-01-01'::date,
               ARRAY[('stuff',13),('more stuff',42),('things',3.14),('etc',0)]);
```